# Get nested XML tags using Nokigiri in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I use this Ruby code in order to get XML tag value:

```
def value_from_xml_for(xml, tag)
  xml_body = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
  hash = Hash.from_xml(xml_body.to_s)
  hash.dig("payment_transaction", tag)
end
```

I wan to get the value for country:

```
<payment_transaction>
   <card_holder>Automation Example</card_holder>   
   <billing_address>     
     <country>DE</country>
   </billing_address>
</payment_transaction>
```

Currently I get nil. How I can extent the code to work with inner XML tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example how to parse XML in nokogiri which is all your method is trying to do:

```
xml_str = <<EOF
<payment_transaction>
   <card_holder>Automation Example</card_holder>
   <billing_address>
     <country>DE</country>
   </billing_address>
</payment_transaction>

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)

doc.at_xpath('//country').to_s
```

So just use nokogiri to parse the xml as that is what it's good at, you don't need hash methods at all.  Your method should be like this:

```
  def value_from_xml_for(xml, tag)
    tag = "//" + tag # assuming you pass 'country' as tag
    xml_body = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
    xml_body.at_xpath(tag)
  end
```

if you want to get just the text of the tag

```
  def value_from_xml_for(xml, tag)
    tag = "//" + tag # assuming you pass 'country' as tag
    xml_body = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
    tag = xml_body.at_xpath(tag)
    tag.text if tag
  end
```

Comment: yes i've updated my answer and give you an additional idea in case you need that